# Why isn't sed using the extended regex mode by default?

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I am using sed. I was using a regex that was correct as far as I could see, but sed did not do anything. Turns out that I was using `\s+` which sed can not understand, and when I switched to `[ ]+` it worked.

So to sum up, I made a regex which for it to work I had to escape almost everything and remove the `\s` for whitespace. Seems that there is a mode to avoid all these which is `-r` So I wanted to ask:

1. Why isn't `-r` the default mode for sed? Why did I have to go to so much trouble to escape everything?
2. `man` says that there is the option `--posix` and that "POSIX.2 BREs should be supported" What does this refer to? NFA/DFA mode?

Comment: As an aside, to match whitespace like perl's `\s+` use `[[:space:]][:space:]]*` in BRE and the same or `[[:space:]]+` in ERE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Re 1) The answer is the same as for any other tool that was improved over decades. :)

You don't want to break existing scripts by changing default behaviour.

Re 2) That has nothing to do with the matching engine; it's just a question of which set of regular expressions is supported. POSIX BRE means "basic regular expression".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding point 2: `gnu sed` uses GNU `BRE` by default. To use POSIX `BRE` you should specify `--posix`